# Where do i insert vidui in bedtime shema?

Tags: shema, viduy-confession

I have read about the importance of saying vidui in the bedtime shema and I would like to start, but I daven nusach ashkenaz whuch doesn't include vidui.  Where should i insert vidui?

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Jacob!

Answer (score 1):

The following nusach ashkenaz siddurim have vidui as the **first item** in the bedtime shema:

[Siddur Otzar Hatefillos](http://www.moshebooks.com/items/421592-%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A8-%D7%94%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%95%D7%AA-)

[The Koren Sacks siddur](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9653011464)

[Siddur Rinas Yisrael p 189](http://www.sefer.org.il/Product/45355/%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%AA-%D7%99%D7%A9%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%9C-%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%9E%D7%98-%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%99)

Artscroll Siddur

so that seems to be a good place.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I daven from the Koren Sacks Siddur (love it!) and the bedtime shema starts with "hareni mochel", not vidui. I have also looked at the Artscroll Siddur and it also starts with "hareni mochel".

Comment: @JacobL Read on.